# CSS grid layout anomaly - for a limited view port size only, only one of three columns shrinks with view port

Tags: css, css-grid

I created a website using a three-column grid in the main section, using fr units to ensure each column takes up an equal amount of space. Each cell contains an image. I use media queries to make the site responsive, and for the most part, it works. However, for some reason, for a view port size of 750px - (roughly) 850px, only the third column shrinks, and the other two stay the same size. For every other view port size the cells and images shrink and grow in unison. Note that the break point is 750 - 1099, and until it getd to about 850 everything shrinks properly.  I have tried vw units instead and that didn't help. What can the problem be? The relevant code is below. Thanks! (note that I removed the actual image links).

```
<main>
  <section class="container">
    <h2>Featured Work</h2>
    <div class="portfolio-grid">
      <div class="project">
        <figure class="fig">
          <img class="project-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/2048x1367" alt="image" />
          <figcaption class="caption">
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p class="project-title">PROJECT 1</p>
        <p class="github-link">Link</p>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <figure class="fig">
          <img class="project-image-portrait" src="http://via.placeholder.com/665x1000" alt="image" />
          <figcaption class="caption">
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p class="project-title">PROJECT 2</p>
        <p class="github-link">Link</p>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <figure class="fig">
          <img class="project-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/4048x3036" alt="image" />
          <figcaption class="caption">
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p class="project-title">PROJECT 3</p>
        <p class="github-link">Link</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

and

```
.portfolio-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 400px;
  grid-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.project {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.project-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.fig {
  margin: 0;
}

.project-image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.project-image-portrait {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {

  .portfolio-grid {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
  }

  .project {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .project-image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .project-image-portrait {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}

/* medium screens */
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 1099px) {

  .project-image-portrait {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: *(note that I removed the actual image links)* ... why? Now we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: If necessary you can use placeholder images from sites like http://lorempizza.com/ or https://placeholder.com/

Comment: @Michael_B I edited the code with placeholder images with the dimensions of the originals

Comment: I'm seeing the images all shrink when the browser window re-sizes, even in the media queries. https://jsfiddle.net/m1boje1w/1/

Comment: Thanks. The issue only occurs between about 750-850 px; during that last 100px before the small screen size query only the third image shrinks while the others remain the same. Can you see that?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far.  It seems the site renders correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Edge.